# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: java, log4j

Can any one help me out of this I am getting this Warning message

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.akak.book.shop.listener.LogContextListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

The class:

```
public class LogContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent ctxEvent) {
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctxEvent) {
    ServletContext ctx = ctxEvent.getServletContext();
    String path = ctx.getRealPath("/") + "logs\\";
    System.setProperty("jlcindia.root.path", path);
    String str = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/com/jlc/jlc-log4j.properties");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(str);
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    log.info("Properties file:"+ str);
  }
}
```

jlc-log4j.properties file : I have specified like this

```
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR.jlc
log4j.appender.jlc = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.jlc.file = ${jlcindia.root.path}/jlcindia.log
log4j.appender.jlc.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatterLayout
log4j.appender.jlc.layout.ConversionPattern = %p %l %m %n
```

Comment: what's in the properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma instead of a period:

```
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR,jlc
                        ^ comma, not period
```

Also it should be Pattern not Patter:

```
log4j.appender.jlc.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
                                                   ^ forgot this 'n' as well
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Sir. By using comma"," this issue will to removed log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.akak.book.shop.listener.LogContextListener). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: After changing the to comma still i am facing the same issue log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.akak.book.shop.listener.LogContextListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.